# What is this yellow flower?

Tags: identification, flowers

This yellow flower was growing in my yard in St Petersburg, Florida. It did not survive my xeriscaping.[image: yellow flower]

Answer (score 13):

I've never seen the species before, but a stab in the dark: Winter Cassia? ([*Senna bicapsularis*](http://www.ars-grin.gov/cgi-bin/npgs/html/taxon.pl?100056) aka *Cassia bicapsularis*). The curved anthers in that group are pretty distinctive, but I'm not at all certain that it is bicapsularis, though.

[image]

<sub>Photo by: [石川 Shihchuan](http://www.flickr.com/photos/epingchris/4589263144/)</sub>

Comment: That appears to be the one. The leaves are what did it for me. The flower is dead on too. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like a buttercup flower. Hard to tell without a picture of the rest of the plant though.  Was the plant tall and skinny, with leaves such as the ones on this [link](http://images.search.yahoo.com/images/view?back=http://images.search.yahoo.com/search/images?p=buttercup%2bplant&ei=utf-8&y=Search&w=670&h=495&imgurl=www.plantillustration.com/images/Buttercup-Ranunculus-illustration.jpg&rurl=http://www.plantillustration.com/portfolio58-Buttercup-Ranunculus.html&size=62KB&name=Buttercup%20illust...&p=buttercup%20plant&oid=334b4dbeabe9937e9d8a32b7c790d03d&fr2=&no=4&tt=16900&sigr=126thdetv&sigi=126b9k85k&sigb=12g59c6p5&.crumb=vtpYZm/lpik)?

Comment: The buttercups that I know of, also have a distinctive seed head, so that is probably something else to look for.